# Not able to setup testcontainers docker

Tags: docker, go, testcontainers

One of our tests requires `docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk` to set up, and when I run the command `go test ./... --tags=integration -v` I keep getting the below error

```
=== RUN   TestLambda
2023/06/15 17:14:21 github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go - Connected to docker:
  Server Version: 24.0.2
  API Version: 1.42
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 7851 MB
Setting HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL to localhost (to match host-routable address for container)
2023/06/15 17:14:22 Failed to get image auth for docker.io. Setting empty credentials for the image: docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.4.0. Error is:credentials not found in native keychain
2023/06/15 17:14:22 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
2023/06/15 17:14:23 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
2023/06/15 17:14:24 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
2023/06/15 17:14:25 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
```

I do have the docker setup, I have logged in. I'm able to pull other dockers like Redis and so on. What am I missing here?

Update 1:
I copied the same code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76491314/9679333) and ran tests. Here is what I got

```
go test ./... --tags=integration -v
=== RUN   TestMongoDB
2023/06/16 08:29:40 github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go - Connected to docker:
  Server Version: 24.0.2
  API Version: 1.42
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 7851 MB
2023/06/16 08:29:41 Failed to get image auth for docker.io. Setting empty credentials for the image: docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.4.0. Error is:credentials not found in native keychain
2023/06/16 08:29:41 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
2023/06/16 08:29:41 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
2023/06/16 08:29:42 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
2023/06/16 08:29:44 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
2023/06/16 08:29:46 Failed to pull image: Error response from daemon: Please run 'docker login', will retry
^Z
[7]  + 40346 suspended  go test ./... --tags=integration -v
```

This is the content of my config file

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
        },
        "credsStore": "desktop",
        "currentContext": "desktop-linux"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide you with a working example of a test taken directly from the official website. If you're unable to solve your issue with this, just provide me more details (e.g. the test code, how you set up the containers, etc.) and I'll update my answer. The only file involved in my example is the `mongo_test.go` file. Below is the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go"
    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/wait"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type mongoDbContainer struct {
    testcontainers.Container
}

func startContainer(ctx context.Context) (*mongoDbContainer, error) {
    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "mongo",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"27017/tcp"},
        WaitingFor: wait.ForAll(
            wait.ForLog("Waiting for connections"),
            wait.ForListeningPort("27017/tcp"),
        ),
    }

    container, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &mongoDbContainer{Container: container}, nil
}

func TestMongoDB(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    container, err := startContainer(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    t.Cleanup(func() {
        if err := container.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("failed to terminate container: %s", err)
        }
    })

    endpoint, err := container.Endpoint(ctx, "mongodb")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(fmt.Errorf("failed to get endpoint %w", err))
    }

    mongoClient, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(endpoint))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("error creating mongo client: %w", err))
    }

    err = mongoClient.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("error connecting to mongo: %w", err))
    }

    err = mongoClient.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("error pinging mongo: %w", err))
    }
}
```

If you run this code you will something that looks like what follows:

```
=== RUN   TestMongoDB
2023/06/16 16:34:46 github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go - Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 24.0.2
  API Version: 1.42
  Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
  Total Memory: 15865 MB
2023/06/16 16:34:46  Creating container for image docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.4.0
2023/06/16 16:34:46 ✅ Container created: 0ad432f3de7c
2023/06/16 16:34:46  Starting container: 0ad432f3de7c
2023/06/16 16:34:46  Waiting for container id 0ad432f3de7c image: docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.4.0
2023/06/16 16:34:46 ✅ Container started: 0ad432f3de7c
2023/06/16 16:34:46  Creating container for image mongo
2023/06/16 16:34:46 ✅ Container created: 8a2117f38bd4
2023/06/16 16:34:46  Starting container: 8a2117f38bd4
2023/06/16 16:34:47  Waiting for container id 8a2117f38bd4 image: mongo
2023/06/16 16:34:47 ✅ Container started: 8a2117f38bd4
2023/06/16 16:34:47  Terminating container: 8a2117f38bd4
2023/06/16 16:34:47  Container terminated: 8a2117f38bd4
--- PASS: TestMongoDB (1.46s)
PASS
ok      testcontainers  1.467s
```

As you can see everything is working fine, even the package `docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk` that causes you trouble.
The only adjustment I had to do was to create a JSON file under my home directory. In my case, the home directory is at the following path: `/home/ivan/.docker`. I added a file called `config.json` with the following structure:

```json
{
    "ServerURL": "https://index.docker.io/v1",
    "Username": "xxx",
    "Secret": "xxx"
}
```

Let me know if this points you towards the right direction, thanks!

Comment: I added more details to the question based on your response.

Comment: Try to adjust the `config.json` as per my suggestion. Probably, you set the `credsStore` in a wrong way. Refer to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-helpers) for further explanation! Also which OS you're running?

Comment: Im running Mac m1 max chip

Comment: I generated a token from the docker account and configured it in the above method. I'm still getting the same issue.